# beforesave vs beforesave.modifiable

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Please, can somebody explain me what's the difference between the events vtiger.entity.beforesave and vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable?

and with vtiger.entity.beforesave.final?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question first of all. Here I have shared my thoughts on the triggers usage in sequential order.

1. **vtiger.entity.beforesave.modifiable**

> This trigger is not used by Vtiger anywhere but it's a **pre-trigger of "vtiger.entity.beforesave"**. When you register this trigger, you will get **$entityData** with Old Record Object and allow you to modify the object which will be used on the next trigger. **Register for another module to override the object**. There is a change of object value that gets overridden by Vtiger registered triggers.

2. **vtiger.entity.beforesave**

> Vtiger uses this event to get the Old Object, set some values for specific fields, and use that object for **Audit tracking**.

3. **vtiger.entity.beforesave.final**

> This event is also not used by Vtiger but it's a **post-event of "vtiger.entity.beforesave"**. You can override the object passed from the previous event. So in other words, you can override Vtiger's default behavior in this event before a record is saved.